# How to change Doughnut color to linear gradient on ChartJS?

Tags: chart.js

I want to change the background for the first element to this color:
linear-gradient(178.18deg, #FD749B -13.56%, #281AC8 158.3%);

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: "doughnut",
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: countArr,
        backgroundColor: ["#F933FF", "#F9A9C6"],
        borderWidth: 0
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    cutoutPercentage: 75,
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: ""
      }
    }
  }
});
```

I've tried do this: `backgroundColor: ["linear-gradient(178.18deg, #FD749B -13.56%, #281AC8 158.3%)", "#F9A9C6"],` No luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create gradient following way:

```
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 450);
gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255, 0,0, 0.5)');
gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25)');
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)');
```

And add `gradient` var to dataset background color:

```
datasets: [
    {
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: gradient,
      borderWidth: 1
    },
]
```

Please check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rje0nvgL/1/)

Edit: to make second element solid color just set array:

```
backgroundColor: [gradient1,'#F933FF'],//1st gradient 2nd '#F933FF'
```

Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/94g0dtvk/1/)

Comment: But, I've two elements. I want first element to be colored gradient and second one to be normal color.

Comment: Check edit fiddle, you have to set each element color  in array

Comment: Thanks for your response. it's working fine on the fiddle, but for some reason the gradient color not showing in my site. It's showing a dark color.

Comment: Share your whole js code in code tags in question body. Possibly that you set gradient before you get canvas id

Comment: Btw, I think it won't work in the SalesForce Aura Component. There's a issue with the createLinearGradient method.

Comment: can you say how to make first doughnut edge rounded? Thank you.

Comment: Didn't do that but it looks a bit harder [check](https://codepen.io/re4388/pen/LwPRbo)